# How to make variable non-reactive in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

Suppose I have this code,

```
<script>
    let timeout = null;

    function handleClick() {
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {console.log('Clicked')}, 100)
    }
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    Button
</button>
```

I don't want the component to re-render when timeout changes. How do I make `timeout` non-reactive?

Comment: If nothing depends on timeout variable, it’s not reactive.

Comment: @hackape Oh okay. Thanks a lot